# How to remove duplicates and only keep rows in which two columns contain same words (Pandas)

Tags: pandas

I've merged two data sets via Left Join on a specific ID.
The right DF however has multiple rows with the same ID but in which there can be different Businesses attributed to the same ID. I only need one row for each ID, and it needs to be the one in which the Businesses in both the left & right data frames match.

One last catch however, is that the businesses in both data frames don't match exactly (hence I haven't merged on this) - the left Data Frame will have part of the business name in whilst the Right DF has the full name and therefore was thinking I could delete duplicates when the Business name in the Right DF business name column does not contain the any word in the original DF name column.

Below is a visualisation which I hope makes more sense

Currently:

| Business Name (Left) | ID | Business Name (Right) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dewes | 1225 | Dewes & Sons Ltd |
| Dewes | 1225 | Stanleys PLC |
| Dewes | 1225 | Shark Ltd |
| Dewes | 1225 | Robots R Us Inc |
| Apple | 1456 | L&L & Co |
| Apple | 1456 | Apple Inc |

What I want

| Business Name (Left) | ID | Business Name (Right) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dewes | 1225 | Dewes & Sons Ltd |
| Apple | 1456 | Apple Inc |

Thanks,
Oli

Comment: You can just drop duplicates : `df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Business Name (Left)","ID"])`

Comment: @Bharath this wouldn't necesserilly mean I would get the correct matching Businesses thought right? For instance, if I dropped duplicates I could end up with 'Dewes' in left but 'Shark Ltd' in the right column which would be wrong?

Comment: if you want to keep the first duplicate, use parameter `keep='first'` and `keep='last'` for last duplicate accordingly.

Comment: If you want to keep it based on alphabetical order, use `sort_values` first, then drop duplicates.

Comment: @Bharath The rows I want to keep could be first, last, or in the middle - and sorting them wouldn't necesserily solve this. Thank you though, I know I need to drop duplicates - I just need at additional part of the Condition now where keep those in which right contains left

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stackoverflow. A possible solution that takes up your idea would be as follows.

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x['Business Name (Left)'] in x['Business Name (Right)'].split(' '), axis=1)]
```

In this case the megered dataframe is only filtered. This works in this from but only if there is only one word in the right column. This should be relatively easy to change, by also splitting the write column and than using .isin().